# Getting stuck Internet explorer automation in vba to calculate the distance between two places using google map

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "https://www.google.com/maps"
    IE.Navigate URL
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

   IE.document.getElementById("searchbox-directions").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values of the start point and the destination to get the route and the distance. Please check my sample below:

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "https://www.google.com/maps"
    IE.Navigate URL
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

   IE.document.getElementById("searchboxinput").Value = "Lincoln Park, Chicago, IL" 'set the destination
   IE.document.getElementById("searchbox-directions").Click

   IE.document.getElementsByClassName("tactile-searchbox-input")(2).Value = "Chicago, Illinois" 'set the start point
   Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   IE.document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox-searchbutton")(2).Click
End Sub
```

The result is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJOnS.jpg